# dyld: Library not loaded: libicui18n.54.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib

Tags: c++, dylib, xerces-c

I'm using an application that links to xerces-c. For some reason this dylib error shows up when I'm running binary. The full message is

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libicui18n.54.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

Any pointers on how to resolve this issue? I'm running OSX. I tried installing icu4c via brew, but the installation is keg-only and the version is currently 58.2.

Answer (score 1):

libxerces has a dependency on `libicui18n.54.dylib` and the loader is not able to find the library in any of the search paths. You probably need to verify that the correct version: `libicui18n.54.dylib` is available in the library search paths. Try removing and reinstalling xerces using homebrew.

```
brew install xerces-c
```